# Removing the numbering in text lines in R

Tags: r, text, extract

I have been given an output in R, and I wish to copy and paste the output into other Microsoft applications. However, each line is numbered. How do I remove the numbers?

For example:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "“.*?”") %>%
  .[[1]]
```

[1] "Gene validation and remodelling using proteogenomics of Phytophthora cinnamomi, the causal agent of Dieback."
[2] "Cultivation Area Affects the Presence of Fungal Communities and Secondary Metabolites in Italian Durum Wheat Grains."
[3] "Genetic analysis of wheat sensitivity to the ToxB fungal effector from Pyrenophora tritici-repentis, the causal agent of tan spot"
[4] "When time really is money: in situ quantification of the strobilurin resistance mutation G143A in the wheat pathogen Blumeria graminis f. sp. tritici."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cat` to copy the output from R console :

```
library(stringr)

str_extract_all(x, "“.*?”") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  paste0(collapse = '\n') %>% 
  cat
```

This will print the output without numbers and would be easy to copy.

Answer (score 1):

The lines are only numbered in the console output.

But don't copy/paste from there. Write the output to a file. For example using `readr::write_lines`:

```
library(stringr)
library(readr)

str_extract_all(x, ".*?") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  write_lines(file = "output.txt")
```

Comment: Error in write_lines(., file = "output.txt") : 
  unused argument (file = "output.txt")

Comment: Works for me. It would help if your example was reproducible (include some example data from `x`).